# Adding ListView item from another Layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

In my app there is two layout first.xml and activity_main.xml. In first Layout there is a button and ListView (Code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this Layout is connected with MainActivty:

```
package com.example.listview2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lvItem;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
        lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);

        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
}
```

And then there is second layout activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ListActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:id="@+id/input">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/input"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this activity is connected to ListActivity:

```
package com.example.listview2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText etInput;
    private Button btnAdd;
    private ListView lvItem;
    private ArrayList<String> itemArrey;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpView();

    }

    private void setUpView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        etInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText_input);
        btnAdd = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);


        itemArrey = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemArrey.clear();

        itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemArrey);
        lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                addItemList();
            }
        });

        etInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    addItemList();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    protected void addItemList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isInputValid(etInput)) {
        itemArrey.add(0,etInput.getText().toString());
        etInput.setText("");

        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }   

    }

    protected boolean isInputValid(EditText etInput2) {
        // TODO Auto-generatd method stub
        if (etInput2.getText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
            etInput2.setError("Please Enter Item");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

The idea of app is very simple. When you start the app, it start MainActivity which is button with ListView. Then you press button to open ListActivity to create new ListView item and this is my question: how can I add to ListView an item from another Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the logic a little bit messed up there. For example, you are referencing in ListActivity a view that does not exist in its layout:

```
lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);
```

`listView_items` is defined in first.xml layout, which means that the `lvItem` reference in ListActivity will be null.

---

In any case, here is a better way to design your app:
1- Have your MainActivity act as the central component of the app. Since it is displaying the listView, it should also be responsible of adding/removing items from it. MainActivity would then start ListActivity when a user wants to add a new item to the list.
2- Have your ListActivity act as a simple interface to get the user's information, and retuning it to your MainActivity.

In this case, the solution is to use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Here is a small rewrite to make it work:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private ListView lvItem;
private ArrayList<String> itemArrey;
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
    lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);
    itemArrey = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemArrey.clear();

    itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemArrey);
    lvItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
           String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
           itemArrey.add(0,result);    
           itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
       else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
       }
    }
}
}
```

Now, for ListActivity, you will keep the same code, but add the following in your `btnAdd` onClickListener:

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",etInput);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

You obviously will want to add input verification and other niceties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot be doing

```
lvItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listView_items);
```

you will get Null Pointer exception when lvItem is used as listView_items does not exist in your activity_main layout.

The right way to make your design work is to send "itemArrey" back as bundle extra in the intent you create for setResult.